# Traversing a 3D array in different order

Tags: c#, traversal, jagged-arrays

I have an array like this: `int[][][] grid_floor_row_col;`

I want to traverse it like this: `int[][][] grid_row_col_floor;`

First I tried to change the for loop, then change the array (copying to a new one), but I just can't do it, my mind doesn't go further...I don't even know anymore if it is possible..

It's the same data, I just need to traverse in different order, reading all the floors per col, per row....Here's how I was traversing:

```
for (int floor = 0; floor < grid_floor_row_col.Length; floor++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < grid_floor_row_col[floor].Length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = grid_floor_row_col[floor][row].Length - 1; col >= 0; col--)
        {
            //do stuff
        }

    }
}
```

Now I'd need to traverse:

```
for rows
  for cols
    for floors
```

Seems so trivial and yet, I can't get it..

Comment: C# naming convention: `gridFloorRowCol`. But you should probably think of a better name anyway (in terms of what the array *represents,* e.g. `rooms`?)

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is not a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In a multidimensional array, you have one array representing a fixed n-dimensional matrix of elements. In a jagged array, you have an array of arrays with possibly different sizes.

Assuming you can convert your definition to `int[,,] grid_floor_row_col`, you can iterate over the dimensions in any order using [`Array.GetLength(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx).

```
for (int row = 0; row < grid_floor_row_col.GetLength(1); row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < grid_floor_row_col.GetLength(2); col++) {
        for (int floor = 0; floor < grid_floor_row_col.GetLength(0); floor++) {
            int elem = grid_floor_row_col[floor, row, col];
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

You can't do this with a jagged array for the simple reason that each floor array can have a different size, meaning a different number of rows per floor (the same applies to the columns per row). If your transformation from `[floor, row, col]` to `[row, col, floor]` is to make any sense, you *need* the same size inside each dimension and thus you should be able to use a multidimensional array.

Comment: I was thinking like c++ arrays..Anyway, I dont want go for the multidimensional array..What bothers me is that I already have the data I want, but I just want to access it in a different way, how can that be not possible? Cant I transform it into another jagged array by copying it to the new one in a different way?

Comment: @Icebone1000 With jagged arrays, you can't know for sure that every array will have the same size in each dimension. Therefore, you won't know how big a `grid_row_col_floor[row][col]` array needs to be to contain all floors. You'd have to first loop through the whole array, collect all array sizes, create the new array using all those sizes and fill it up. That's two expensive deep loops just for a transformation.

Comment: @Icebone1000 Of course, if you *know* the arrays should have the same size in all dimensions, you could cheat a bit and use `grid_floor_row_col[0].Length` for the rows and `grid_floor_row_col[0][0].Length` for the floors, assuming that `grid_floor_row_col[0][0]` will always exist. Still, it's not very elegant and for your use case a multidimensional array would be much better suited.